# How to turn the spark df output

Tags: apache-spark

I am posting the below program to turn the output into a different format as method in the last section of the program :

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    
    object PeTPairing {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    
        val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PET").master("local").getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._
        val pet = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).csv("data/other/pet.csv")
        val owners = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).csv("data/other/owner.csv")
        val pet_data = pet.select("id", "owner_id", "breed", "sex")
        val animalPair = pet_data.as("a1")
          .join(pet_data.as("a2"), $"a1.breed" === $"a2.breed" && $"a1.sex" =!= $"a2.sex" && $"a1.owner_id" =!= $"a2.owner_id").
          join(owners.as("a3"), $"a1.owner_id" === $"a3.id", "full_outer").select($"a1.breed".alias("breed1"),$"a2.breed".alias("breed2"),$"a1.sex".alias("sex1"),$"a1.owner_id".alias("owner1"),$"a2.owner_id".alias("owner1"),$"a2.breed".alias("breed2"),$"a2.sex".alias("sex2"),$"a3.id".alias("owner_id"))
        //animalPair.show()
       val finalOutput= animalPair.groupBy("owner_id").agg(count("sex2").alias("count")).sort(col("count").desc, col("owner_id"))
    finalOutput.show()
```

Current output of above program is :

```
    1.  +--------+-----+
    2.  |owner_id|count|
    3.  +--------+-----+
    4.  |       1|    9|
    5.  |       6|    6|
    6.  |      21|    4|
    7.  |       2|    3|
    8.  |       8|    3|
    9.  |      13|    3|
    10. |      20|    3|
    11. |      14|    2|
    12. |       3|    0|
    13. |       4|    0|
    14. |       7|    0|
    15. |      10|    0|
    16. |      11|    0|
    17. +--------+-----+
```

But I want to turn the above output into the following one:

```
 1. owner_id,count
    2.  1,9
    3.  6,6
    4.  21,4
    5.  2,3
    6.  8,3
    7.  13,3
    8.  20,3
    9.  14,2
    10. 4,1
    11. 3,0
    12. 7,0
    13. 10,0
    14. 11,0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
     print("owner_id,count\n")
     finalOutput.rdd.map(_.mkString(",")).collect.foreach(println)
```